# Is it necessary to select a carrier when buying an iPhone online from Apple?

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers

I am planning to buy an iPhone X during an upcoming USA trip. During the buying process on the Apple Store, I am asked to select a carrier between AT&T, T-Mobile, Sprint and Verzion. I dot not have any sim from the USA and I am not planning to have one for using the iPhone X ever in the US.

Is this important to activate the iPhone?

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/233224/ and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304509/

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that in the US carriers have and use slightly different technologies and different frequencies than their competitors. Though I believe T-Mobile and AT&T use similar technology and frequencies. Not sure abut the other two.

I would suggest checking the website of the carrier you use at home and see what they use so you can select a phone that is the most compatible with their cellular network.

Comment: Thank you but I think it's not possible. I updated ny question

Answer (score 1):

Currently Apple only allows the sale of the iPhone X directly from their website to come with carrier locked versions. If you want a new iPhone, the iPhone 8 & 8 Plus models can be purchased without a carrier and SIM free.

All newly purchased iPhone's do need to be activated with a carrier SIM. If you don't activate it, then you can't get past the activation screen, even with iTunes.